# How Can I do not display the XRRichText ,if there is no data?

Tags: asp.net, ado.net, devexpress, report

I am using the `XRRichText.visible=off` if there is no data, but still it throwing some spaces in report. I do not want those spaces if there is no data. 
Just want to display none & no spaces . How can I do this?

[image]

The upper spaces are just XRRichText.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the property ProcessNullValues for the labels with the issue as ‘Suppress and Shrink’.
The purpose of this property value is: If a control receives a null value, it is not printed (without adding blank space in its place).
The property has two more values:
Leave – A control is always printed.
Suppress - If a control receives a null value, a blank space is printed instead.
[image]